# How to display post list inside post

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I need help. I creating one plugin for live results from competitions. I will need 2 post types for having competition and class. To simplify situation let's say that competition is event, which happening sometimes even few days or even weeks, and class is like that event's timetable, and question is, how to show event's that related to that competition in single competition post type post. And also in address competition must be like this example.com/competition/examplecompetition
And event like this
example.com/competition/examplecompetition/exampleevent